# Adding my Widget to Kivy App __init__ leads to blank screen and Warning

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I started with the Kivy Crash Course a few days ago and wanted to write a  memory game. My App Class looks like that:

```
   class MemoryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.mgw = MemoryGameWidget()
        return self.mgw
```

This code works with my .kv file.

I always check my code with Pycharm Code Inspect. Pycharm suggests to move the attribute to **init** :

```
class MemoryApp(App):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.mgw = MemoryGameWidget()
```

But when I run that code i get an empty window and this warning:

```
 [WARNING           ] <__main__.MemoryGameWidget object at 0x02BCC490> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.
```

Could somebody explain what is happening and what I did wrong?

Comment: I forgot to add the build function from the 2nd class:      def build(self):

        return self.mgw

Comment: Does `MemoryApp` inherit from `Widget` or a layout class?

Comment: MemoryGameWidget inherits from GridLayout and MemoryApp from App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But putting it in `__init__`, you instantiate the widget before its kv rule has been loaded, and so this rule is not applied. I would leave it in the build method and ignore the pycharm warning.

Edit: Actually, an appropriate way to resolve the warning may be to add 'self.mgw = None' in the `__init__`, thereby satisfying pycharm that the attribute exists properly without changing how it's actually properly set up in the build method.